# What's the best way to update SharePoint document content via .NET?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

**I have the URL of a SharePoint (2013) document and also the path to a network document.**

(Both the SharePoint document and the network document can be very large. In this specific case, the SharePoint document is an image-only PDF and the network document is a text-searchable version of the same document.)

**I want to update the content of the SharePoint document with the content of the network document.
What is the best way to do this in .NET?**

(I'm trying to avoid adding a new document to SharePoint, because of document ID considerations.)

Thanks!

Comment: So basically you want to convert your network document to PDF and overwrite sharepoint version, right? If yes then you might take a look at sharepoint conversion services. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff181518(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Sorry. I should have been a bit clearer. The network document is already a text-searchable PDF. I want to replace the image-only PDF content with the text-searchable PDF content.

Comment: What do you mean "replace"? You can simply overwrite it. But i guess you do not want that - you want to convert PDF to image only and then upload?

Comment: In a sense you are right - I just want to overwrite it. I am asking what methods of what objects of what models would be the best choice considering that the document might be up to 400 megabytes.

Comment: Well, if you are considering sharepoint server object model then it has only Add method of SPFileCollection class which accepts binary data or Stream object. It does not care how you gonna get it. You can easily grab file stream using File class or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues you have to tackle.  1) SharePoint must be configured to accept large files, 2) IIS must be configured to handle large requests, and 3) IIS must be configured to wait long enough for the upload to complete.

To configure SharePoint to accept large files, change the **Maximum Upload Size** for the web application in Central Admin.

To configure web limits in IIS, check out the Microsoft documentation at iis.net. ([www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/weblimits](http://iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/weblimits)).